# Cupsfilter encoding errors "â€œxâ€​" and ineffective custom page sizing while printing/converting html to pdf in terminal

Tags: pdf, terminal, character-encoding, cups, page-size

[**cupsfilter**](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-cupsfilter.html) is what I am using through **terminal** to convert [**this .html file**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pdh5gobdgt0vlk/r8fXc3bY4iefJn2jGzRIp.html?dl=0) into [**this PDF**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vn51gjsfqnu7h03/r8fXc3bY4iefJn2jGzRIp.pdf?dl=0).

**Having two issues:**

1. Notice the **encoding issues** with PDF *between these two pictures*:

   - [Converted PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2F7c.png)
   - [Original Text Before Conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjhPj.png)
2. Defining **custom width and height of pages** of the document,

   - Have tried:

     - `cupsfilter -o media=custom.216x1000mm /Users/coloradoman/Desktop/r8fXc3bY4iefJn2jGzRIp.html > /Users/coloradoman/Desktop/testing123.pdf`
     - `cupsfilter -o page=custom.216x1000mm /Users/coloradoman/Desktop/r8fXc3bY4iefJn2jGzRIp.html > /Users/coloradoman/Desktop/testing123.pdf`
     - `cupsfilter -o pagesize=custom.216x1000mm /Users/coloradoman/Desktop/r8fXc3bY4iefJn2jGzRIp.html > /Users/coloradoman/Desktop/testing123.pdf`
     - `cupsfilter -o media=216x1000mm /Users/coloradoman/Desktop/r8fXc3bY4iefJn2jGzRIp.html > /Users/coloradoman/Desktop/testing123.pdf`
     - *and many more versions of this...*
   - nothing seems to take effect, all I get is the standard A4 page size...

Comment: [How to copy/paste text from PDF generated by cups-pdf? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335848/how-to-copy-paste-text-from-pdf-generated-by-cups-pdf)